# Custom List Adaper not displaying correct background

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a an android app that populates the screen with rows and based on if they have been clicked the background should either be red or green.

[image]

If you click on the rows the background will change to the opposite color.  The issue I have been having is if I click on a row and scroll down then scroll back up the row usually isn't set to the correct color anymore.

**Scroll Down Once**

[image]

**Scroll Down Second Time**

[image]

The rows seemingly arbitrarily change backgrounds when I scroll.

I believe the issue is with the custom list adapter.  Here is the code:

```
public class MyCustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Coin> {

private ArrayList<Coin> yourArray;

public MyCustomListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Coin> yourArray){
    super(ctx, R.layout.my_custom_list_item, yourArray);
    this.yourArray = yourArray;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Re-use rows to save battery
    View row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //We inflate our custom view for the ListView item
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        row = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_custom_list_item, null);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }
    Coin coin = yourArray.get(position);
   // String[] name= yourArray.get(position);
    String year = coin.getYear();//name[0];
    String specialty = coin.getSpecialty();//name[2];
    String mintage = coin.getMintage();//name[1];
    String mint = coin.getMint();
    int have = coin.getHave();

    TextView tvListItem1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_year_tag);
    TextView tvListItem2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_mint_tag);
    TextView tvListItem3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_specialty_tag);
    TextView tvListItem4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_mintage_tag);

    tvListItem1.setText(year);
    tvListItem2.setText(mint);
    tvListItem3.setText(specialty);
    tvListItem4.setText(mintage);

    if(have == 1) {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.have);
    }
    else {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.need);
    }
    return row;
}
```

If i remove the

```
 if(have == 1) {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.have);
    }
    else {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.need);
    }
```

It does not have this problem (but the rows are not colored when created).

I change the color of the row in the `onItemClick` in the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private CoinsDataSource datasource = new CoinsDataSource(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addValues();
    setUpComponents();
}

private void setUpComponents(){
    ArrayList<Coin> myValuesToDisplay = getDatabaseContent();
    MyCustomListAdapter adapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(this, myValuesToDisplay);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
private ArrayList<Coin> getDatabaseContent(){
    datasource.open();
    ArrayList<Coin> coins_list = datasource.getAllCoins(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    return coins_list;
}

public void addValues()
{
    //datasource = new CoinsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    datasource.createCoin("1856", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1857", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1858", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1859", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1860", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1861", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1862", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1863", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1864", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1865", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1866", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1867", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1868", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1869", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1870", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1871", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1872", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1873", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1874", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1875", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1876", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1877", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1878", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1879", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1880", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1881", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1882", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1883", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1884", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1885", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);


    datasource.close();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String year_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_year_tag)).getText().toString();
    String mint_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_mint_tag)).getText().toString();
    String speciality_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_specialty_tag)).getText().toString();
    datasource.open();
    int x = datasource.adjust_db(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE, year_text, mint_text, speciality_text);
    if(x == 0)
    {
        TableRow row1 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
        row1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.have);
    }
    else
    {
        TableRow row1 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
        row1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.need);
    }
    datasource.close();
}
```

Any ideas why these changes aren't staying when I scroll down?

Comment: A `ListView` recycles. Maintaining state is your responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

first we want to define this Adapter:

```
public class MyCustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Coin> {

private ArrayList<Coin> yourArray;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// This will hold the View Contents
public class RowContent{
       TextView tvListItem1;
       TextView tvListItem2;
       TextView tvListItem3;
       TextView tvListItem4;
}

public MyCustomListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Coin> yourArray){
    super(ctx, R.layout.my_custom_list_item, yourArray);
    this.yourArray = yourArray;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//Re-use rows to save battery
RowContent theRow;
if (convertView == null) {
    theRow = new RowContent();
    //We inflate our custom view for the ListView item & set it to convertView
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_list_item, null);

    // Reference the UI Elements
    theRow.tvListItem1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_year_tag);
    theRow.tvListItem2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mint_tag);
    theRow.tvListItem3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_specialty_tag);
    theRow.tvListItem4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mintage_tag);

      // set the Row Content as the Tag for the View
      convertView.setTag(theRow);
     } else {

    // the row will be recycled
    theRow = (RowContent) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Coin coin = yourArray.get(position);
    // String[] name= yourArray.get(position);
    String year = coin.getYear();//name[0];
    String specialty = coin.getSpecialty();//name[2];
    String mintage = coin.getMintage();//name[1];
    String mint = coin.getMint();
    int have = coin.getHave();

    theRow.tvListItem1.setText(year);
    theRow.tvListItem2.setText(mint);
    theRow.tvListItem3.setText(specialty);
    theRow.tvListItem4.setText(mintage);

    if(have == 1) {
         convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.have);
    }else {
         convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.need);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This is the proper way to recycle items...

Then you Want to do this instead of manually changing the table row.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

 private CoinsDataSource datasource = new CoinsDataSource(this);
 // Have your MyCustomListAdapter be a class member
 private MyCustomListAdapter adapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addValues();
    setUpComponents();
 }

private void setUpComponents(){
    ArrayList<Coin> myValuesToDisplay = getDatabaseContent();
    // Build the adapter and set it to the member variable
    adapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(this, myValuesToDisplay);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private ArrayList<Coin> getDatabaseContent(){
    datasource.open();
    ArrayList<Coin> coins_list =          datasource.getAllCoins(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
   return coins_list;
}

public void addValues()
 {
    //datasource = new CoinsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    datasource.createCoin("1856", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1857", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1858", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1859", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1860", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1861", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1862", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1863", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1864", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1865", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1866", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1867", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1868", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1869", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1870", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1871", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1872", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1873", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1874", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1875", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1876", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1877", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1878", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1879", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1880", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1881", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1882", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1883", "D", "NEW TEXT", "2000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1884", "P", "MORE TEXT", "17,450,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);
    datasource.createCoin("1885", "D", "Not NULL", "24,600,000", 0, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE);


    datasource.close();
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Update your data in the database
    String year_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_year_tag)).getText().toString();
    String mint_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_mint_tag)).getText().toString();
    String speciality_text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_specialty_tag)).getText().toString();
    datasource.open();
    int x = datasource.adjust_db(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY_FLYING_EAGLE, year_text, mint_text, speciality_text);
   datasource.close();

    // Get this coin from the adapter, and update the coin data object
    Coin coin = (Coin) adapter.getItem(position)
    coin.setHave(x);

    // Tell your adapter its data has changed (this is what i was referring to)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: In the `onItemClick` what adapter are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry didn't specify, define your adapter as a class member. see above i will post your whole activity...

Comment: Well I feel dumb, that should have been obvious which adapter you were talking about

Comment: @Dommol nice catch with me missing theRow reference for finding TextViews

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting a break after the if (have = 1) when coloring it color.have? It looks like that piece of code does not execute. You'll need to, in onClick, find the coin clicked and update its have value to 1, and vice-verse to zero when deselecting.

Currently you are only coloring the row when you select it.
When the row is removed from screen then display again it will get its color from the adapter which decides on its color from the coin's have value.